# How to compare json attribute ignoring type in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

In mysql 5.7, I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`price` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
`attributes` JSON NULL DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

Then I `INSERT INTO`item`VALUES (1, 'trademark', 250000.00, '{"sn": "5108174", "type": 1, "group": "2501 2502 2503 2506 2507 2508 2509 2510 2511 2512", "regDate": 1210694400}');`

I can select the row by:

`select * from item where price = '250000.00'`

Or

`select * from item where price = 250000.00`

because mysql ignore normal field type by default.

But it's different when I filtered by json attribute:

`#Return empty
select * from item where json_extract(attributes, '$.type') = '1';`

`#Return one row
select * from item where json_extract(attributes, '$.type') = 1;`

Since attribute.type is number, I can convert it to string to ignore type:

```
select * from item where concat(json_extract(attributes, '$.type'),'') = '1';
```

or

```
select * from item where cast(json_extract(attributes, '$.type') as char) = '1';
```

Unfortunately, the magic was lost when attribute.type is string

`INSERT INTO`item`VALUES (1, 'trademark', 250000.00, '{"sn": "5108174", "type": "1", "group": "2501 2502 2503 2506 2507 2508 2509 2510 2511 2512", "regDate": 1210694400}')`

So when I receive attribute.type from url param, it's hard to get it's real type to select data.

Is there any way to compare json attribute ignoring type like normal field ?

Comment: MySQL doesn't ignore the data type, does an implicit conversion, see [12.2 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html). However, in JSON data type columns see [11.6 The JSON Data Type::Comparison and Ordering of JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-comparison). Try to convert a numeric type: `CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(\`attributes\`, '$.type') AS UNSIGNED) = 1`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes I can solve the problem by CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(`attributes`, '$.type') AS UNSIGNED) = 1 in this case. But, as I said, the params passed by url is all string, so it's hard to determine _type_ is string or number in /?type=1. I just wanna a way to implicit everything to string like CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(`attributes`, '$.type') AS CHAR) = 1, howerver, if type is stored as string, it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried using [- >>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) operator?. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rr1PruhfTJYsXLpmed47ap/0).

Comment: Thanks god! You saved me. Thank you very much.